# Sending React Native Android Events to JavaScript from a Service

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin

I am trying to emit an event using `DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter` in React Native, but because I wish to call it from a Service, I don't know how to get the `reactContext`. My code looks like this:

```kotlin
class TimerService : Service() {
    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
       val reactContext = ???
       reactContext
         .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
         .emit("tick", "tock");
    }
}
```

If the essence of what I am trying to do is wrong I'm happy to change anything and everything.
For more context, what I'm trying to do is keep track of rest timers in-between sets at the gym. Full code can be found [here](https://gitea.presley.nz/brandon.presley/Massive/src/commit/1d0d7c2fff267d2077d76bddd48df7b4ee9d479f/android/app/src/main/java/com/massive/TimerService.kt). I wanted to add a page to display the currently running rest timer, where the state is being stored in `TimerService`.

I tried to cast `applicationContext` to `ReactContext` like:

```
  (applicationContext as ReactApplicationContext)
    .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
    .emit("tick", "tock");
```

But was given an error saying I can't cast `ApplicationContext` to `ReactApplicationContext`. I also tried to figure out how I could pass `reactApplicationContext` down to my `Service`, but got a bit stumped on trying to parcel it for an `Intent`.